# Удаление свойств из миксина в Less

Tags: css, less

Есть задача по которой нужно сделать так что бы можно было удалять свойства из миксина.

Пример

```
@my_list: "color", "width"; // Here we define a list variable with 2 values: color and width
.my-mixin () {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: green;
}
.my-class-with-excluded-props {
    /* Here we remove color and width properties from the included mixin. */
    .my-mixin() - @my_list;
}
.my-class-with-all-props {
    .my-mixin();
}
```

Вывод должен быть таким

```
.my-class-with-excluded-props {
    /* Here we remove color and width properties from the included mixin. */
    background: red;
}
.my-class-with-all-props {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: green;
}
```

У меня есть понимание как просто присвоить свойствам значение None, но я не могу понять как их вообще удалить. Буду благодарен за любой совет

Так же при удалении в миксине в котором присутствует вложенность только внешние свойства должны быть удалены

Пример

```
@my_list: "color";
.my-mixin-1 () {
    width: 100px;
    color: green;
    .a {
        color: white;
     }
}
.my-class {
    .my-mixin-1() - @my_list;
}
```

Ожидаемый вывод

```
.my-class {
    width: 100px;
}
.my-class .a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд избыточное количество миксинов только путает. Понимаю когда нужно реально сдлать миксин, который нужно вставлять во все щели как например цвет сайта, что бы в будущем поменять параметры в одном месте и сайт перекрасится полностью. Или вычислительные параметры какие-то нужно вписать, чтобы не вспоминать каждый раз, какое там было уравнение. Но зачем же так извращаться не понимаю))

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи я такого же мнения о миксинах и их применении, но задание есть задание